# TypeScript v1.5, possibility to require in a specific part of code

Tags: typescript, typescript1.5

**Context**

I m developping an application in which I need to load an array in a method like

```
 getRouteFromLink(link:String):Array {
        array = require(link);
        return array;
    }
```

Does it exist something giving me the possibilité to make without declaring it at the top of the file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, Typescript supports [Optional Module Loading](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-optional-module-loading-and-other-advanced-loading-scenarios). From the Handbook:

```
declare var require;
import Zip = require('./ZipCodeValidator');
if (needZipValidation) {
    var x: typeof Zip = require('./ZipCodeValidator');
    if (x.isAcceptable('.....')) { /* ... */ }
}
```